# Input to Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

How do I give segmented images (labels) as input to CNN? Is giving segmented images in addition to the input image useful for the classification using CNN?

Comment: In semantic segmentation, your labels are typically images where each pixel encodes a class label. You pass these labels to your model just like you would pass labels for a simple classification task. I suggest you have a look at some implementations of semantic segmentation models in keras: https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet

Comment: Segmented images are not the same as labels. The OP should clarify what he means (maybe with an image)